# Parameterized Tests with Function Output

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I'm working on some fairly complicated test scenarios with PyTest, and I was hoping to encapsulate the test setup for various scenarios in some functions and then make those scenarios available to a test using parameterization.

Here is a simplified example:

```py
def scenario01():
    # complicated setup
    ...
    return {
        "name": "scenario01",
        "cond1": cond1,
        "cond2": cond2
    }

def scenario02():
    # complicated setup
    ...
    return {
        "name": "scenario02",
        "cond1": cond1,
        "cond2": cond2
    }

# is it ok to call these functions in the decorator
@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_data", [scenario01(), scenario02()])
def test_my_func(test_data):
    name = test_data["name"]
    cond1 = test_data["cond1"]
    cond2 = test_data["cond2"]
    assert cond1 && cond2 #this isn't important
```

Is there any downside to doing something like this?

I like this because, as a reader, its obvious where the fixtures are coming from and their not magically defined in some `conftest.py` file, but I'm not sure if there is some side effects that may be happening that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

If the functions aren't computationally expensive, there's no *harm* in it. If it *were* computationally expensive, I might move the function invocation inside the test method, like so:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_data", [scenario01, scenario02])
def test_my_func(scenario):
    test_data = scenario()
```

The issue with computationally expensive things at module level is that they'll occur during test collection, regardless of whether those tests actually end up running.

However, if the scenarios *aren't* expensive, I might gain a few points in readability by pulling the scenario contents into actual parametrized fixtures, and moving the `name` into the ParamSet's `id`, so it will show up in the pytest output

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(("cond1", "cond2"), [
    pytest.param(data['cond1'], data['cond2'], id=data['name'])
    for data in [
        scenario01(),
        scenario02(),
    ]
])
def test_my_func(cond1, cond2):
    assert cond1 and cond2  # this isn't important
```

Comment: oh, I like this! I'll definitely try it out. Thanks!